# Как сделать сервер из компьютера на Win7 для использования на ubuntu | jupyter notebook

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, windows-7, jupyter-notebook

У меня есть компьютер на Win 7 с неплохой gpu.Как можно настроить сервер, чтобы использовать на ubuntu(Для jupyter notebook)

Comment: снести Win7  и установить дистрибутив ubuntu-server?